# Pattern extract using Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I am trying to use regex for word extraction in python, since I am beginner and not experienced in regex I want you to help me, I have this String :

```
Deadline for NSF-BSF programs in Elementary Particle Physics – Theory; Particle Astrophysics and Cosmology – Theory; Quantum Information Science (NSF deadline is Dec. 14)
```

And I want the output to be a list of area or research in this word, so the output should be:

```
[Elementary Particle Physics, Particle Astrophysics and Cosmology, Quantum Information Science]
```

could any one give regular expression to identify this pattern using `re.findall()`.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming that (1) `' in '` is the indicator that the words you're interested in are are starting, and that (2) all areas are separated by `';'` and that (3) all areas end with  `- Theory` or something in parenthesis, we can get the list you're looking for. Note: these are the assumptions that must be consistent across all input sources if the below code is to work as expected.

```py
import re

src = "Deadline for NSF-BSF programs in Elementary Particle Physics - Theory; " \
      "Particle Astrophysics and Cosmology - Theory; " \
      "Quantum Information Science (NSF deadline is Dec. 14)"

_, out = src.split(' in ')
out = [re.split(r'( - Theory)|\(.*\)', o)[0].strip() for o in out.split(';')]

print(out)
```

`out`:

```
['Elementary Particle Physics',
 'Particle Astrophysics and Cosmology',
 'Quantum Information Science']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I appreciate it, that all I want, it worked like a charm, since all the text patterns is the same as you assumed early.